# Onclick inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why this is happening, I am looping through a number ( Object.size(pagination) ), and setting an onclick event for each number. Upon clicking one of the buttons, it echos the last available page number, instead of the one I clicked.

```js
for (var i = 1; i < (Object.size(window.pagination) + 1); i++) {
  $("#supportTicket_pageNumber").append("<li class=\"\"><a style=\"cursor: pointer;\" class=\"supportTicket_pageNumber_" + i + "\">" + i + "</a></li>");
  $(".supportTicket_pageNumber_" + i + "").click(function() {
    console.log("Page number: " + i);
  });
}
```

The classes with the numbers also get inserted fine, https://gyazo.com/92c556117bbd42bb7a16e7832b60af39

[image]

Comment: A better solution is this: `for (var i = 0; n= Object.size(window.pagination) ; i<n;  i++) {
  $("#supportTicket_pageNumber").append("<li class=\"\"><a style=\"cursor: pointer;\" data_page=\""+(i+1)+"\" class=\"supportTicket_pageNumber\">" + (i+1) + "</a></li>");
}

$(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".supportTicket_pageNumber",function() {
    console.log("Page number: " + $(this).data("page"));
  });

})`

Comment: I had a few typos. Please review

Comment: I've corrected them. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to create a closure.

Wrap it inside an IIFE

```
 for (var i = 1; i < (Object.size(window.pagination) + 1); i++) {
   (function(x) {  // closure start here
     $("#supportTicket_pageNumber").append("<li class=\"\"><a style=\"cursor: pointer;\" class=\"supportTicket_pageNumber_" + x + "\">" + x + "</a></li>");
  $(".supportTicket_pageNumber_" + x + "").click(function() {
    console.log("Page number: " + x);
    });
   }(i)) // end here, passing the context of i
}
```